# jquery error on page without any scripts

Tags: jquery

getting the following error with jquery.

getting this without any jquery syntax in the head sections.

any ideas?

jquery 1.9.1

```
TypeError: a is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

...function(b,d){var f=d.nextPage,g,h=new a.Event("pageremove");d.nextPage&&(g=f.jq...
```

my head is:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you running this locally?

Comment: Hi, yes. what does this impact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure jquery mobile should come after jquery as it depends on it.  Try switching the order they are loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Change the line order - put the jQuery line before the jQuery-mobile one.

Answer (score 0):

Include scripts/css in this order:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

Since jQuery mobile and jQuery UI both rely on `jquery.min.js`, they must be included after `jquery.min.js`.